# Shorthand for setting the left and right margins to the same value

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm curious if there is an entirely equivalent one-line shorthand for the following selector:

```css
.foo {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

I could use something like:

```css
.foo {
  margin: 0 30px;
}
```

but it isn't clear to me this is equivalent, e.g., the 0 might create a different final result if multiple styles apply to an element.

Comment: Isn't it `margin: unset 30px unset 30px`, the order is top,right,bottom,left.

Comment: @Shizukura when using shorthand the left value is top, bottom and right value is left, right.

Comment: *how the auto acts when styles are combined.* it depends on the other properties. It has different behavior. There is at least 3 (1) when dealing with block element non positionned (2) positionned element (3) flexbox

Comment: When is `unset` a valid value for `margin`? [This link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) doesn't mention it.

Comment: unset is a valid value for any property (like inherit,initial, revert, etc) and that link is a very bad reference. The worst

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. Typically `auto` is used for centering.

> The browser selects a suitable margin to use. For example, in certain
>   cases this value can be used to center an element.

The initial value however, is 0.

So unless you specifically need to use `auto`, you would want the following.

```
.foo {
  margin: 0 30px;
}
```

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) explains how the margin property can be used.

Comment: Yeah the `auto` thing probably didn't make sense, I should have used 0. I don't know if `0` is really equivalent, since e.g., the result can be different if more than one style applies to an element? E.g, before maybe the top and bottom margin was coming from another style, but now the 0 overrides due to the specificity rules.

Comment: @BeeOnRope in your second example, `auto` would still override any existing values. The only way to prevent that would be to use your first example rather than shorthand.

Comment: Do you mean 0 would override any existing values? I removed the reference to `auto` as I had mistakenly thought that `auto` was the default, but in fact it is zero.

Comment: @BeeOnRope If a top and/or bottom margin (other than 0) had been set on `.foo` prior to declaring the rule in question, then yes it would override it assuming there is not another rule with higher specificity as you said.

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
.foo {
  margin: 0 30px 0 30px;
}
```

Comment: the top and bottom margins must be default, not 0

Comment: it's not mentioned by OP. @shizukura

Comment: @Shizukura The default value is 0.

Comment: The default value might be 0, but that doesn't mean that _not specifying a top/bottom margin is the same as 0_, does it?

Comment: Yes it would be 0, and it is not going to override any values coming from any other container.